# Concept Of Observable collection in C#

Tags: c#, collections

How can I use a property in event handler that is defined in a class, which is used inside a Observable Collection.

My code is like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.IO;

namespace BindingImages
{
    class MyImage
    {
        private string _path;

        public MyImage(string path)
        {
            _path=path;
        }

        public string Path
        {
            get { return _path;}

        }

    }

    class MyPhotos:ObservableCollection<MyImage>
    {

        DirectoryInfo _directory;



        public string Path
        {
            set
            {
                _directory = new DirectoryInfo(value);
                Update();

            }
            get { return _directory.FullName; }

        }

       private void Update()
       {
           foreach (FileInfo f in _directory.GetFiles("*.jpg"))
           {
               Add(new MyImage(f.FullName));
           }
       }


    }


}
```

This is my window's code:

```
namespace BindingImages
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Window1.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        public Window1()
        {
            this.DataContext = new MyPhotos();
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void listbox1_SelectionChanged(object sender,SelectionChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            string selection=listbox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
            if ((selection != null) && (selection.Length != 0))
                    {
                        ImageSourceConverter imgConv = new ImageSourceConverter();
                        ImageSource imagesource=(ImageSource)imgConv.ConvertFromString(selection);
                        img.Source = imagesource;    // here i'm having a problem
                    }

        }
    }
}
```

This is my Xaml Code:

```
<Window x:Class="BindingImages.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:ph="clr-namespace:BindingImages"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ph:MyPhotos x:Key="Photo" Path="D:\Photos" />

    </Window.Resources>
        <Grid>
        <TextBlock FontSize="26"  HorizontalAlignment="Center">Pick an Image From below List</TextBlock>
        <ListBox Height="250" Width="420" Margin="10,0,10,480" SelectionChanged="listbox1_SelectionChanged"   Name="listbox1" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Photo}}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Image Source="{Binding Path}" Width="100" Height="100"></Image>
                </DataTemplate>

            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

        </ListBox>
            <Image  Height="250" Margin="155,50,12,14" Name="img" Stretch="Fill" ></Image>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

So I have to fire an event so that selected image from the list box shoul be displayed as an individual image when I select any image from the list box?

I facing a problem when I handle the event as you can see the code to handle the event .??

Comment: One thing more that i dont want to Override string function to return the property?? So help me out.

Comment: Where are you setting the value `MyPhotos.Path` property?